# Is It Possible to Have Separate Endpoints Listed in the Firebase Console When Exporting Express App to Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

Right now I'm exporting an express app to firebase functions that has all my endpoints enclosed

```
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

But in my firebase console, only one entry shows up.

[image]

Is there any way I can get an entry for each endpoint (e.g. api/endpoint1, api/endpoint2)? The only way I see that happening is creating a separate express app for each endpoint.  I'd like to separate endpoints in order to track performance and improve logging.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to have individual express app endpoints appear in the console.  This is not the first time someone has asked to be able to do this, so I recommend you file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with a discussion of the value you'd get out of having them broken out.